# Solr facet search returning different result and count

Tags: solr, facet

I am trying to implement Solr facet search functionality and testing my query on the server via the url. When I run this query

---

`http://localhost:8080/solr3/core0/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=ipad&facet.field=brand&facet=on`

---

I get something like

---

`...<lst name="facet_counts"><lst name="facet_queries"/><lst name="facet_fields"><lst name="brand"><int name="Apple">37</int>`

---

But when I use `apple` as facet query like

---

`http://localhost:8080/solr3/core0/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=ipad&facet.field=brand&facet=on&fq=apple`

---

I expect to get 37 results, but query returns `<result name="response" numFound="402" start="0">`

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you apply the filter:  `q=ipad&fq=brand:apple`

Don't repeat the facet unless you want multi-select facets (and even then, it's more complex than that).